# How to add vertical lines (rules) to the left of first column and right of last column using multicol package

Tags: rules, multicol

When using the package `multicol` for say 2 columns, the output is `....|....` using the code below.

I'd like a way to add a rule to the left of the first column and to the right of the last column, so that the output looks like `|....|....|`

These 2 extra rules can be in the margin if needed instead of in the text area.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.01pt}

\begin{document}

  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]
  \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I tried using `\fbox` around everything and tried using `minipage` but none worked well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to achieve is to add `\hss{\columnseprulecolor\vrule\@width\columnseprule}\hss` in all the column inside the `\page@sofar` macro of `multicol` package:

```
\makeatletter
\def\page@sofar{%
   \process@cols\mult@rightbox
       {\ifvoid\count@
          \setbox\count@\hbox to\hsize{}%
        \else
          \wd\count@\hsize
        \fi}%
   \count@\col@number \advance\count@\m@ne
   \mult@info\z@
    {Column spec: \the\full@width\space = indent
                  + columns + sep =\MessageBreak
        \the\multicol@leftmargin\space
        + \the\col@number\space
        x \the\hsize\space
        + \the\count@\space
        x \the\columnsep
     }%
\ifvmode\else\errmessage{Multicol Error}\fi
   \nointerlineskip
   \setbox\z@\hbox{p}\global\dimen\tw@\dp\z@
   \@ifundefined{maybe@reverse@columns}{}{\maybe@reverse@columns}
   \moveright\multicol@leftmargin
    \hbox to\full@width{%
     \process@cols\mult@gfirstbox{%
       \ifdim\dp\count@>\dimen\tw@
         \global\dimen\tw@\dp\count@ \fi
       \hss{\columnseprulecolor\vrule
              \@width\columnseprule}\hss
              \box\count@
     }%
     \ifdim\dp\mult@rightbox>\dimen\tw@
       \global\dimen\tw@\dp\mult@rightbox \fi
       \hss{\columnseprulecolor\vrule
              \@width\columnseprule}\hss
     \box\mult@rightbox
       \hss{\columnseprulecolor\vrule
              \@width\columnseprule}\hss
     \rlap{\phantom p}%
    }%
 \kern-\dimen\tw@
 \ifdim\dimen\tw@ = \mc@gridwarn
   \PackageWarning{multicol}%
     {Very deep columns!\MessageBreak
      Grid alignment might be broken}%
 \fi
}
```

\makeatother

You can place this before `\begin{document}`.

---

**Note:** In 2014 version of `multicol` you may find an error with the command  `\maybe@reverse@columns`. For that reason I have now amended the macro with:

```
\@ifundefined{maybe@reverse@columns}{}{\maybe@reverse@columns}
```

Thanks for @Nasser, who pointed out the problem.

Comment: fyi, I just found the above code causes clash with multicol package in 2014. Error is `Undefined control sequence.
\page@sofar ...tw@ \dp \z@ \maybe@reverse@columns
    \moveright \multicol@leftm...
l.12860 \end{multicols}
?` I was using the above in 2013 texlive with no problem. Something changed in texlive 2014 multicol and now there is clash. Just in case someone tries it in 2014.